# recursive equation with a

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> (1) relation this $a_{n+1}+a_n=2^n$.With $a_0=0$.

**What i did was:**

multiply by 2  and it is $2a_{n+1}+2a_n=2\times 2^n$  this is (2)
and on the first i did $a_{n+2} +a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}$.

I (2)-(3) and i have

$$2a_{n+1}+2a_n-a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=0
\\2a_1+2a_0-a_{2}-a_1=0
\\2\times1+0-2-1=0
\\-1$$

Comment: I tried to edit what you wrote so that it actually makes sense, but I have no idea what you did on the last two lines. Why are you trying to find $a_1$ and $a_2$ in this way? Having got it into the form $$2a_{n+1}+2a_n-a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=0$$ you can now solve this second order recurrence relation exactly for any $n$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: i dont try find a1 i just put n=0 and i have 2a1+1 .I think i did wrong here

Comment: so it will be 2*2 +2*0-2-1 that the result is 4+0-3 that leads result 1

Comment: its fine now? or not?

Comment: But _why_ did you put $n=0$? Isn't the question asking you to find $a_n$?

Comment: no ,its saying "solve the recursive equation an+1+an=2n .With a0=0"

Comment: And no, its not fine as it would not give you "$1$". It would give you $a_1-a_2=0$. It is true however that you can use the condition $a_0=0$ to get that $a_1=a_2=1$, but this will not help to get a general expression for all $n$.

Comment: how then? it will be to solve this recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it says to solve the recursive equation, this means you must find a formula for $a_n$, for general $n$. This is done, as you did, by getting an equation $$2a_{n+1}+2a_n-a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=0\\\implies a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-2a_n=0$$Now try a solution of the form $a_n=p^n$ for a constant $p$. Then $$p^2-p-2=0\\\implies (p-2)(p+1)=0\\\implies p=2,\,p=-1$$
So we get a general solution as a superposition of the two solutions, $$a_n=A 2^n+B(-1)^n$$
You can then sub in the conditions for $a_0$ and $a_1$ to get rid of the constants $A$ and $B$. Can you give that a go?

Comment: man you are absolutely gorgeous.Thank you a lot .I am very greatful you help me