# How to solve with constants A and B when I have $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have an issue. As a result, I have $a_n = A \, 2^n + B \, (-1)^n$.  The post is from here:

> [recursive equation with a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829924/recursive-equation-with-a)

How to continue to the solution?

What I did was to take $a_0 = A \, 2^0 + B \, (-1)^0$.

Comment: What is your equation?

Comment: $$a_n=A\times 2^n+B\times (-1)^n$$?

Comment: yes this is.I take 0 and i replace zero to n.If you could do it with simple way to got it.Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Your question is how to solve for unknown constants $A$ and $B$?  You have two linear equations and two unknowns... $\begin{cases}A+B=0\\2A-B=1\end{cases}$.  Now that it is written like this, surely you know how to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For $n=0$ you will get $$a_0=A+B=0$$
And for $n=1$ we get $$a_1=2A-B=1$$

Adding both equation you will get $$3A=1$$

Comment: ok thanks a lot :) In 5 minutes i accept :D .Great job

Comment: Who gave me the $-1$?

Comment: Graubner i have no idea who